# MS Access find and replace text in column fields multiple tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access database with over 100 tables that conditionally need columns renamed.

Each table needs to be opened and any field names that contain the following string, "AAA_" needs to be replaced with "BBB_".

Is there a way to automate this process? I'm trying to avoid doing this exercise manually. I don't really know vba and I experimented with some update queries to no avail. When using the native query design functionality, it only seems to look at the corresponding records for a field name, but not the field name itself.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function could be used to do what you want. You need to adjust it your needs as the conditions you refer to are not clear

```
    Function renameField(tableName As String, fieldName As String, newFieldName As String) As Boolean

        On Error GoTo EH

        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim td As DAO.TableDef
        Dim fd As DAO.Field

        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set td = db.TableDefs(tableName)

        For Each fd In td.Fields
            If fd.Name = fieldName Then
                fd.Name = newFieldName
                renameField = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        
        Exit Function
        
    EH:
        renameField = False
        
    End Function
```

An adjustment could look like that

```
 Sub renameFldsInAllTables()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fd As DAO.Field
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    For Each td In db.TableDefs
        For Each fd In td.Fields
            ' If Left(fd.Name, 4) = "AAA_" Then
            If InStr(1, fd.Name, "AAA_", vbTextCompare) Then
                fd.Name = Replace(fd.Name, "AAA_", "BBB_", 1, 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there a way to adjust the function so it looks anywhere in the string? The substring to replace can exist in the middle. For example, in the old name, "G_LOI_AAA_DT" I want the "AAA' to be replaced with "BBB."

Comment: I adjusted the code so that it will look anywhere in the field name for "AAA_".

Comment: This is going to save me hours of work! I truly appreciate it, thank you for your help and insight!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very weird request. Why are you changing all kinds of field names in a database?  It seems like you have a very poor, or weak, data design!!

Put this code behind a button on a form.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim counter1 As Long
Dim counter2 As Long
Dim tbl As TableDef
Dim fld As Field
    For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    Debug.Print tbl.Name
        'If tbl.Name = Table Then
            For Each fld In tbl.Fields
            Debug.Print fld.Name
            If fld.Name = "Pictures" Then
                fld.Name = "Picture"
                Exit For
            End If
            Next
        Exit For
        'End If
    Next
End Sub
```